# Auto click when user scrolls to the end of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an infinite scroll feature on my site but it isn't working. 
My code:

```
var post = {}
post.load_moreBtn = $('#home_load_more');
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    post.load_moreBtn.trigger('click');
}
post.load_moreBtn.on('click', function () {
    $(this).html('<img src="' + base_url + 'images/core/loader2.gif"/>');
    post.load_more_messages($(this).attr('data-last_id'));
});
```

If I put an alert in place of the trigger it works,also if I remove the scroll detection bit, the load more works fine. Just can't get it to autoload, please help.

Comment: You don't bind anything to the scroll event

Comment: You mean you can't bind anything to scroll events?

Comment: You absolutely can, but the code you posted does not

Comment: What can i bind? $(window).scroll?

Comment: Yeah; `$(window).on('scroll' ...` would be preferred

Comment: It seems the trigger function isn't working?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22863/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-saffron-harris)

Comment: Sorry @ExplosionPills I slept off haha, tell me when you're back on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy with jQuery:

```
$(function(){ //on document ready
    $(document).scroll(function (e) { //bind scroll event

        var intBottomMargin = 300; //Pixels from bottom when script should trigger

        //if less than intBottomMargin px from bottom
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {
            $("#home_load_more").click(); //trigger click
        }

    });
});
```

I bind this in the

Comment: Thanks :) I got it to work already. But i'll take your intbottommargin idea, it makes sense, you don't have to get to the exactly bottom of the page to tigger the click event. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help in some way =)